# Using Visual Studio Online to build Windows Store Apps?

Tags: windows-store-apps, azure-devops

I have a Windows Store Application (Windows 8.1), hosted on a GIT repo on Visual Studio Online.

I created a build definition, left all the default values as they were, ran the build and downloaded the artifacts.

I didn't find the Powershell script used to side load (install) the application, instead I found an .exe file.

What can be missing to generate the Powershell script needed to install the app?

Comment: Where did you run the build? Was it successful?

Comment: Sounds like you have built the app, are you perhaps meaning "deployment"?

Comment: yes, the build was successful, when I downloaded the artifacts, I found an exe file and not the powershell script

Comment: What PowerShell script? Have you marked your PowerShell script as 'content' so that it is pushed to the bin folder?

Comment: no, the powershell script file is generated automatically from when you create the app packages in Visual Studio, I expect the same when you build the project in Visual Studio Online

Comment: @MinaSamy, are you using the vNext build system or XAML build?

Answer (score 0):

The default build configuration is copying the files in "bin" folder to artifacts, that's why you see exe file.

To copy the package files to artifacts, please configure your build definition as following:

In "Visual Studio Build" step, add following argument in "MSBuild Arguments":

```
/p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AppxPackages\\"
```

And in "Publish Build Artifacts" steps, set "Path to Publish" as following:

```
$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\AppxPackages
```

Answer (score 0):

To package Windows Store App during the TFS build process, you can (assume you're using XAML build):

1). Set MSBuild Arguments to be: /p:DeployOnBuild=true;DeployMethod=Package /p:DefaultPackageOutputDir="$(TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)"\StoreAppPackage

2). Set **Output location** to be 'SingleFolder' or 'PerProject'.

Then, after you queue one build, you will find one folder called StoreAppPackage in the TFS Build Drop folder. You can then find the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 file.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find the Output location option, where is it?

Comment: @MinaSamy, on the build definition, go to Process -> 2.Build -> 4. Output Location.